# TypeError issue when using databricks sql driver for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, databricks

I am running into an issue when trying to connect to databricks using the Node.js driver, the documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-nodejs) or [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/nodejs-sql-driver.html#databricks-sql-driver-for-nodejs). I am basically using their example as shown under **Usage** in the github link

```
const { DBSQLClient } = require('@databricks/sql');

const client = new DBSQLClient();

client
  .connect({
    host: '********.databricks.com',
    path: '/sql/2.0/warehouses/****************',
    token: 'dapi********************************',
  })
  .then(async (client) => {
    const session = await client.openSession();
    console.log("I should be reaching here if connected");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I am just switching out their connection values for mine. I can confirm the client is being created but I am unable to connect. There isnt much documentation on what the error is but it is as follows:
`TypeError: this.thrift.createHttpConnection is not a function at eval (HttpConnection.js:26:43)`